# Learn Laravel Framework MVC

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I learn Laravel Framwork very easy way?
Lots of Tutorials are on youtube but I don't know which tutorial are best..

so I think if anybody suggest me about it, it will be very helpful for me.

Thanks

Comment: Any tutorial will do as long as you're coding continuously.

Comment: You can start with Laracast videos, it's a kind of "official" tutorial source, most of Laravel videos are free. After that you need to read the documentation and search other information fonts like Medium.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn Laravel the best place to learn Laravel is

https://laracasts.com

seriously, Jeffery way is the best person you could learn from, easy to understand 
good examples and voice of an angel, plenty of content for free as well.

Nothing comes close when it comes to learning Laravel IMO

Answer (score 0):

You have to first really Understand the MVC (model view controller). Once you get that concept you can learn any framework quicker.  (Symfony, Laravel etc).

Not sure what your knowledge is with MVC but start there.  Then begin peeling Laravel as such